# Trying to access a field of type discriminator in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class base on my map, it inherited two new classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Business" namespace="Business.Test">
<class name="BaseExample" table="base_example" abstract="true" discriminator-value="0">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="Int64" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="domain" type="Int16" not-null="true" force="true" />
    ....
    ....
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Business"   namespace="Business.Test">

<subclass name="Example1" extends="BaseExample" discriminator-value="1">
....
....
</subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

everything works fine, but if I ask for that field, for example:

```
var Clients = ClientFactory.GetAll().Where(c => c.UserData.BaseExample.Domain == 1);
```

throw this exception: Exception Message: could not resolve property: Domain of: Business.Entities.BaseExample

how can tell if it is of one class or another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discriminators are meant to be used behind-the-scenes from NHibernate (see Rippo's example). The idea is that you query the **class** and the appropriate discriminator from that class's mapping is injected into the query.

However, if for some reason you need that information in a property it is valid to include it as a property. That means

```
<class name="BaseExample" table="base_example" abstract="true" discriminator-value="0">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="Int64" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="domain" type="Int16" not-null="true" force="true" />
    <property name="domain" column="domain" type="Int16" update="false" insert="false" />
    ....
    ....
</class>
```

it is important that you declare the property as readonly (`update="false" insert="false"`) since this is a column managed completely by nhibernate.

Comment: Also on your class I would include:-

`public int Domain { get; protected set;}`

Comment: that would be useful if you want it visible in the application code, but not required if you only want it for queries

Comment: Do you need need a setter for a fully mapped property?

Comment: What i mean is that you can avoid the property alltogether in the mapped class by adding the attribute  access="noop" to the property definition. That way the property value is not fetched during queries but you can use it when quering eg with HQL.

Answer (score 1):

Using `QueryOver` to get all records in the `base_example` table for class `BaseExample` you would do this:-

```
session.QueryOver<BaseExample>().List();
```

to get all `Example1` records you would do this

```
session.QueryOver<Example1>().List();
```

to get all `Example2` records:-

```
session.QueryOver<Example2>().List();
```

In other words NHibernate is clever enough to add the where clause `Domain=1` or `Domain=2` in the query for you automatically.

Also it should be noted if you want all the records from the base table and have a loop, then you could do this:-

```
var list = session.QueryOver<BaseExample>().List();
foreach(var item in list) {
  if (item is Example1)
    Output(Example1) //Do something with Example1
  if (item is Example2)
    Output(Example2) //Do something with Example2
}
```